# tmux determine if a pane is marked

Tags: tmux

I want to create a tmux keybind which sends a set of keystrokes to the marked pane. This is convenient for implementing a hotkey that runs something so I don't have to manually focus another pane and then come back.

But I'd like for this key to not do anything if there's no marked pane present. I've looked in the manpage and found nothing obvious that I can use to check this state.

Comment: I think you mean marked window, in the standard terminology for _tmux_.

Comment: Oh, wow, I was totally wrong about that. It turns out that what I was thinking of as a "marked window" was really just a window with one marked pane in it.

Comment: Yeah... now it is true that you can only have one pane marked, so the notion of "marked window" does exist (its simply the window which contains the marked pane)

Answer (score 2):

To target the marked pane you can use `-t '~'` or `-t '{marked}'`.

In this case it is simply a matter of `send -t '~' <keys here>`.

A more generic way to get the marked pane in your shell would be `tmux display -p -t '~' '#D'`.